# Redirection with subdirectories urls in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

When with my browser, I do a call to http://myhost/tiles/yellow/1/2/3.png, I would expect to get content from http://myhost/cache/yellow.png
My configuration is the following

```
    location /cache/ {
      alias /my/path/cache/;
    }

    location /tiles/ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rulestiles;
    }
    location @rulestiles {
      rewrite "^/tiles/([a-zA-Z1-9]*)/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{6}/[0-9]{6}\.png$" /cache/$1\.png permanent;
    }
```

What do I miss? Is it because I don't use capture everywhere as I don't need all parameters?

I also don't want to use symbolic links as I would need hundred millions of symlinks for only some hundred real files...

Thanks for any guidance/help

Comment: Thanks for being constructive ;) I removed the reference you mentioned. I used before Apache, hence this question and I configure all my servers.

Comment: Sorry. A bad start on my side. Thanks for your answer. Why do I want to rewrite this? I have patterns to query maps tiles with the same colors. I don't want the overhead of an application whereas url rewriting should be enough to serve same images. I can always deploy this project https://plaintiles.herokuapp.com but I don't see the point to use an application to serve static files whereas I'm supposed to serve only static files with just different patterns in routing.

Comment: Your url doesn't match regexp in rewrite directive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  `Alexey Ten` comment in my question, I was able to correct my various errors.

First, my regex was wrong so I wasn't capturing parameters when testing

Then, I also changed `rewrite` to `proxy_pass` to keep my url the same

```
location /cache/ {
    alias /my/path/cache/;
}

location ~ "/tiles/(?<section>[a-zA-Z1-9]*)/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,6}/[0-9]{1,6}.png$" {
    proxy_pass http://my.tested.ip.code/cache/$section.png;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

where `my.tested.ip.code` is the server IP.